# Python type hinting: class of given type

Tags: python-3.x, generics, type-hinting

Sharing something I found in case it might be helpful to someone.

What I wanted to do is to create a generic method that receives a *class (type)* and returns an instance of that type. Since I'm *strongly* in favor of static-typing (pun intended), I wanted to have it statically typed. This is something that could be useful if you're working on IoC service provider, for example.

Say that in Java, you can have a signature like this:

```java
public <T> getInstance(Class<T> clazz)
```

I wanted to see how I'd do that in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')
def instantiate(self, t_type: Type[T]) -> T:
    return T()   # or whatever your code does

# example
class Foo:
   def some_method(self):
       pass

f = instantiate(Foo)    # IDE recognizes f is Foo (even without you hinting it as `f: Foo`)
f.some_method()         # IDE recognizes and suggests it when you're starting to type the method name.
```

Hope somebody finds it useful.

Comment: You should use `Callable[[], T]` instead of `Type[T]`. If `T` takes arguments in `__init__`, then `T()` will throw a type error only with the former not latter.